# How to delete a VM from datastore if it is locked?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-disk

we are using Esxi 4.1. One of the VM is there in datastore which could not be deleted due to the files were locked.

We were trying to reload the VM into inventory by creating new VM with custom option(there we would be given option to select existing virtual disk). But we were unable to select that.

I think as it is locked , we were either unable to delete or load it again?

How to delete the file completely?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you can try:

- You can try restarting mgmt-vmware on the host, and see if you can
  delete it after.
- Login to the service console and kill the PID of the VM then delete.